# Unable to compare time with custom Function Google App Script

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets

I'm creating a custom function where I would like to update the start time of a schedule depending if they had Overtime.

For example, Employee1 entire schedule is from 8:45 AM - 7:00 PM, however this person had Overtime before his real shift started, so I'm trying to update his start time based on that, but when I try to compare the start time with the Overtime start time, for some reason even when they both are equal, the script doesn't recognize them, below my code:

```
function calculateStart(shiftStart, shiftEnd, scheduleState, scheduleStateStart, scheduleStateEnd) {
  var newScheduleState = [];
  var res;
  var newShiftStart = "Start";
  var sLen = scheduleState.length;
  
  //Creating new array that contains only the schedule information for one day
  for (i = 0; i < sLen; i++) {
    res = String(scheduleState[i]).slice(0, 3);
    if(res != "Req"){
      newScheduleState.push(scheduleState[i]);
    }else{
      break;
    }
  }

  //Checkig if shiftStart needs to be updated based on Overtime
  sLen = newScheduleState.length;
  for (i = 0; i < sLen; i++){
    if(String(newScheduleState[i]) === "Overtime"){
      newShiftStart = "Yes, this is overtime";
    //NOT SURE WHY the next line is false 
    if(shiftStart == scheduleStateStart[i]){
      newShiftStart = "Yes, they are the same" + shiftStart + ' - ' + scheduleStateStart[i];
      if(String(newScheduleState[i+1]) === "CLINIC"){
        newShiftStart = "End Clinic"
        //newShiftStart = scheduleStateEnd[i+1];
      }else{
        newShiftStart = "Overtime"
        //newShiftStart = scheduleStateEnd[i];
      }
    }else{
      newShiftStart = "Not the same " + shiftStart + ' --- ' + scheduleStateStart[i];
    }
    }
  }
  return newShiftStart;
  // Returns: Not the same Sat Dec 30 1899 09:47:04 GMT-0500 (GMT-05:00) --- Sat Dec 30 1899 20:02:04 GMT-0500 (GMT-05:00)
}
```

And below and image of the parameters:

[custom function](https://i.stack.imgur.com/7e3at.png)

Adding a [link to sample file here](https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1jFfLwSHz58g6HcpVJYZwCv0pYpDG1wqNH3zxJABzWg0/edit?usp=sharing)

Comment: Can you share a sample sheet that we could work on?

Comment: Sure, you can find it here [link](https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1jFfLwSHz58g6HcpVJYZwCv0pYpDG1wqNH3zxJABzWg0/edit?usp=sharing)

Comment: @NaziA Date equality will always fail. Instead, you need to compare against the primitive value using `.valueOf()` or `getTime()`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When trying to check the values by using `JSON.stringify`, they returned:

[image: output]

The first one is the `shiftStart` while the 2nd is `scheduleStateStart[i]`.

What you need to do is first, access the `scheduleStateStart[i]` first element which is `scheduleStateStart[i][0]`.

I did `JSON.stringify` both of them then compare. The condition should look like this:

`if(JSON.stringify(shiftStart) == JSON.stringify(scheduleStateStart[i][0])){`

This should return `End Clinic`

[image: output]

Note that when you opt to remove `JSON.stringify` on the variables, it will return false.